# Difference between HitTestBehavior.opaque and HitTestBehavior.translucent? (GestureDetector)

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

```
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    child: GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, <=== SEE HERE
      onTap: () {},
      child: child,
    ),
  );
```

I don't understand the difference between opaque and tanslucent. Based on my code both of them don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HitTestBehavior.translucent` allows you to also trigger the Widget behind your top Z-Index widget.
The `HitTestBehavior.opaque` will only trigger the top Z-index widget.

Imagine you have a `Stack` with two `GestureDetector`. the `.opaque` will trigger only the first one and the `.translucent` will trigger both.

I don't really understand why you need 2 `GestureDetector` here. Maybe try something like this:

```
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, <=== SEE HERE
    child: child
  );
```

In your code the 2 `GestureDetector` are listening to the same Gesture and only one will trigger the action. Here it's the second one who triggers the actions empty function

Answer (score 1):

After many search I found that maybe HitTestBehavior only effect on Stack.

see issue [#18450](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450)

Parent and child are not effect by HitTestBehavior, they are hitten both.

And in Stack, if your Container has color property, it is always opaque.

Container with translucent behavior should be with no color itself, like the issue say.

My test code is in follow

```dart
Listener(
      onPointerUp: (event) {
        print("Container");
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Listener(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onPointerUp: (event) {
                print("A");
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 50,
              child: Listener(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
                onPointerUp: (event) {
                  print("B");
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 10,
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```